# Getting the sum of a value per hour and then getting percentages based on a high and low condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that I want to modify. The current query sums the usage per hour. I want to modify it to be able to just get the percentages of the value greater than 610 and a percentage below 610. Also need to make the two percentages equal 100.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN h.TotalUsage <= 610 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END)/COUNT(*) * 100 as InPermitRangePercentage,
       (1-SUM(CASE WHEN h.TotalUsage <= 610 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END)/COUNT(*)) * 100 as OverPermitRangePercentage
FROM (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), DateTm, 121) DateHour, SUM(Usage) TotalUsage
       FROM ChlUsage
       WHERE DateTm Between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) and DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1)
       GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), DateTm, 121)) h
```

current data results

```
  DateHour    /   TotalUsage
----------------------------
2021-03-16 15 / 197.701171875
2021-03-16 14 / 490.859375
2021-03-16 13 / 578.30078125
2021-03-16 12 / 523.654296875
2021-03-16 11 / 417.15625
2021-03-16 10 / 245.65625
2021-03-16 09 / 406.498046875
2021-03-16 08 / 403.06640625
```

Desired results

```
InPermitRangePercentage / OverPermitRangePercentage
           74.70        /           25.30
```

Comment: Please share sample input and output.

Comment: I encourage you to add your sample data as DDL+DML (temp table create + insert)... means anyone wanting to assist doesn't have to type it all in... And we need to see raw sample data not your current results.

Comment: I edit my original post, I don't have access to the temp table create etc because of the platform I am on.

Comment: @JShaffer there is always [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) and we are only asking you to write the scripts, not run them. And table variables don't usually require much in the way of permissions.

Comment: Regarding that whole `DATEADD/DATEDIFF` shebang, have you heard of `DATEFROMPARTS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the final solution

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN h.TotalUsage <= 610 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END)/COUNT(*) * 100 as InPermitRangePercentage
    , (1-SUM(CASE WHEN h.TotalUsage <= 610 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END)/COUNT(*)) * 100 as OverPermitRangePercentage
FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), DateTm, 121) DateHour, SUM(Usage) TotalUsage
    FROM ChlUsage
    WHERE DateTm Between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) and DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1)
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), DateTm, 121)
) h
```

Answer (score 1):

Conditionally sum the values of interest and then divide by the total sum. Note the 1.0 to ensure you get a decimal value rather than an int.
To ensure you get 100% you need one of your conditions to include equals, otherwise you fail to count the case when `Usage = 610`

```
  , SUM(Usage) TotalUsage
  , SUM(CASE WHEN Usage < 610 THEN Usage ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 / SUM(Usage) TotalUsageLowerThan610
  , SUM(CASE WHEN Usage >= 610 THEN Usage ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 / SUM(Usage) TotalUsageGreaterThanEqual610
```

Comment: when I try to use the sum case statements the results are all one's in the first column and all 0 is the second column